# Laravel blade templates error

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code:

in laravel/resources/views/users.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('content')
<p>
    Here's your content
</p>
@stop
```

in laravel/resources/views/layouts/main.blade.php

```
<html>
  <head>
    {{-- Common Header Stuff Here --}}
  </head>
<body>
<div class="navigation">
  @section('navigation')
    <a href="/">Home</a>
    <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
  @show
</div>
<div class="container">
  @yield('content')
</div>
```

in routes.php

```
Route::get('users', function()
{
    return View::make('users');
});
```

When i launch my site (localhost/laravel/public/users) It prints only:

> @extends('layouts.main')

[image]

what's wrong here? I'm using laravel 5

Thanks in advance, i'm newbie with laravel

FIIIIIIIIXEEED

> @extends can't be indented, you can't put anything before it even whitespace.

Comment: I just tested on my Laravel website. If you use "return view('users');" you can indent @extends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in Laravel 5 you cannot use return View::make('users'); That's only for pure HTML content (already compiled). If you want to use blade templates, you should instead use :

```
return view('users');
```

Comment: `view` is a helper and contraction for `View::make`.